# How do I force-quit Git Bash?

Tags: windows, git, bash

I'm in Nano via ssh on my server via git bash. And I can't do anything. I can scroll up and down but I ***'ed it up somehow.

How do I quit it?
I tried to find the process but windows can't tell me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using PowerShell

```
kill -n bash
```

[Stop-Process](http://ss64.com/ps/stop-process.html)

Comment: bash: kill: bash: invalid signal specification